# In Tzolk'in, can you be at negative points?

Tags: tzolkin

On the second turn of the game, I angered the Gods when I needed to beg for food. I wasn't up on any of the temple tracks, so moving backwards is supposed to give me negative points. At this point, I was still at zero victory points. Can my total VP drop below zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  This is explicitly stated on page 13 of the rules.

> "On each temple, you score the number of victory points indicated by your current step only. Note that if you are on the bottom step, you will lose vic- tory points. Victory points can go negative."

However it appears from your question you are scoring the -1 when you move onto that space.  This is incorrect as you only score points on the temples during the mid game and endgame food days.

Comment: We realized we were doing the VP on the temple tracks incorrectly when we got to the halfway point. This still didn't prevent me from going negative though. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Negative scores are more common with the prophecies expansion. Plus, if you couldn't go negative, there'd be no reason to gather food for the first food day, and possibly the second, especially if you're gathering resources for a late-game building spree.